# Optimizing purchase querying in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am implementing an online application shop with Rails. Its data model is shown as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many purchase_records
  has_many items, :through => purchase_records
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many purchase_records
  has_many users, :through => purchase_records
end

class PurchaseRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end
```

It has a page showing available items and there prices, and if the user has purchased the item, the price will be a download link, just as App Store does. A view helper is written to help generate such links:

```
def download_link(item)
  # generate a download link
end

def item_link(item)
  if current_user and current_user.items.where(:id => item.id).first != nil
    # User already purchased it
    download_link(item, 'book-price')
  else
    # Not purchased yet, show price and link to its details
    link_to item.price, item
  end
end
```

`current_user` is defined by devise. It works fine except for it costs 20 extra database queries for a page with 20 items, since it needs to check if the user has purchased the item or not for every single item. I am wondering if it can be optimized, for example, to pre-load purchased items of current user, but I have no idea how to write it in a view helper.

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented downloadable content for a client.

What I did was write an instance method on the user class that retrieves the user's purchased items, e.g.:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def downloads
    self.orders.collect { |o| o.products }.flatten
  end
end
```

You could use the include? method to check if the user purchased the item, e.g.:

```
def item_link(item)
  if current_user && current_user.downloads.include?(item)
    download_link(item, 'book-price')
  else
    link_to item.price, item
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, while this is a bit more explicit, it will still loop through the user's orders every time item_link is hit. I would suggest optimizing this with Rails low-level caching where you may clear the cache every time the user logs in or completes a purchase.

A Rails low-level cache may look like this:

```
def downoads
  Rails.cache.fetch("user-downloads-#{self.id}") do
    self.orders.collect { |o| o.products }.flatten
  end
end
```

And call the following to clear a cache:

```
Rails.cache.delete("user-downloads-#{self.id}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set the user's purchased items to an instance variable in the controller. Then you're only hitting the database once:

```
# app/controllers/items_controller.rb
def index
  @purchased_items = current_user.items
end

# app/helpers/items_helper.rb
def item_link(item)
  if @purchased_items.include?(item)
    download_link(...)
  else
    link_to ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't write that in a view helper. You make a scope on the user model called **purchased_items** where you would check all of the items a user has purchased.

Since you didn't put up the source code for User, Item and whatever their relationship is, I can only give you that general hint.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have added the data model in the problem.